# Passing Segmented Control Index value from one class to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4

The First View has a Segment Control, an segment is selected then a button is selected from within the same view displaying a new view (a table view).  I want to use the Index that was selected in the Segment Control from the previous view in a SQL Query, so I only need to have the value in memory, not displayed.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the Segmented Control Index, you must be calling a method to know the selected index. Create a variable in the parent class to store the index of segmented control selected index, And pass it to some variable in destination class. In this way you can store the index to the new class.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would create a property on your tableview subclass and pass the value to it.

Alternatively store it temporarily in NSUserDefaults, or use notifications.